# ChromeDriver user preferences ignored

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver 3.3 and ChromeDriver 2.28 (32bit). My slave machine is Windows 7 running Chrome 57.

When Chrome starts I am trying to use ChromeOptions over RemoteWebDriver to disable the "save your password" pop-up using the parameter "password_manager_enabled".

However, it seems to have no effect at all. I have tried many variations around ChromeOptions, JSON strings and simple strings but all to no avail.

```
ChromeOptions cOpt = new ChromeOptions();
cOpt.addUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
var capabilities = chromeOpts.ToCapabilities() as DesiredCapabilities;
// Add OS, Platform capabilities etc
string gridConnectionURL = "xxxx"
driver = new CustomRemoteDriver(new Uri(gridConnectionURL), capabilities, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
```

Does anyone know the "correct" way to set this preference so it works?

Comment: I have just realised that ChromeDriver seems to create a temporary profile in the location C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp. When I look at this profile the setting DOES appear. But Chrome seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to replace

```
//cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("password_manager_enabled", "false");
cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```