# How to close browser popup in robot framework?

Tags: google-chrome, robotframework

After login in Chrome browser, I am getting a save password popup from the browser. I want to handle that popup and want to close that using Robot Framework
[Browse popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47bYP.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered before with a pure Python context. This answer continues on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793277/chromedriver-user-preferences-ignored) for a working Robot Example.

The popup you see is generated by Chrome itself. It's not an HTML alert. For this reason none of the Selenium2Library keywords will have any effect on it. Nor wil settings cookies or javascript.

[image]

These settings can be manually set using the [chrome://settings](http://chrome://settings) link. Go to **advanced settings** and then scroll down to **Passwords and Forms**. Untick the second item and this will prevent the popup.

[image]

To do the same automatically in Robot Framework the WebDriver needs to be started with additional preferences:

```
 Chrome With Preferences
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver

    ${prefs}    Create Dictionary   credentials_enable_service=${false}  

    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-infobars 

    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}

    Go To    https://secure.url.com
```

This key things here are `credentials_enable_service=${false}` where it is important to use `${false}` and not *false*, as the latter is interpreted as a string and then added to Chrome as *"false"* instead of the correct value `false`.

The second item is that preferences are not added as *arguments* but through assigning a `dictionary` to the `prefs` property of the `ChromeOptions()` object like so: `add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is real to be honest (as it's property of the browser.) Are you having issues with that? The only thing you can dismiss is javascript alert and probably the best way to handle this is:

```
${alert} =    Get Alert Message    dismiss=${dismiss}
```

I have this in my test teardown with Run Keyword and Ignore Error, it makes me able to fetch optional js alert content and debug (also dismisses it do the rest of the suite can be executed.)

Answer (score 0):

Three Ways To do do it.

1) Many a times, Once pop-up appear on screen and Disappear a cookie is set which you can view in developer console-> application. If you set this cookie with value using **Add Cookie** keyword. Pop- up wont appear.

2) if first doesn't work, then open developer tools and monitor the local store from developer tools -> application and close the pop-up. U will notice some variable with a value is stored in local storage. You can set that value using your script and u wont see the pop-up while executing variable.

3) If first and second doesn't work, the pop-up is most likely linked to a javascript variable. set java script variable using **Execute Javascript** Keyword and your problem must be solved.

Talk with your dev team, to see which way will work for you.